# Observing live data from an API is not updating ui when data changes

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-viewmodel, mutablelivedata, android-diffutils

I am trying to develop a football app demo. Data comes from an API from the [api](https://www.football-data.org/) 
It loads data as expected when app started, but when score of match changes, ui is not updating for scores by itself. I am using *DiffUtil* *getChangePayload()* to detect changes in *score* and *status* fields of *Match* objects which comes from the response. But it is not triggering when live match data changes. What am i missing? 
**P.S.** I put layout in SwipeRefreshLayout and when i refresh, it gets scores and update the ui. But i want to see the match status and scores updating by itself.
Here is my code:

```
class MatchesViewModel(
    app: Application,
    private val repository: MatchesRepository
): AndroidViewModel(app) {

    val matchesToday: MutableLiveData<List<Matche>> = MutableLiveData()

    init {
        getMatchesToday()
    }

    fun getMatchesToday() = viewModelScope.launch {
        safeMatchesToday()
    }

    private suspend fun safeMatchesToday() {
        if (Constants.checkConnection(this)) {
            val response = repository.getMatchesToday()
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                response.body()?.let {
                    matchesToday.postValue(it.matches)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
class MatchesTodayFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentMatchesTodayBinding? =null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private lateinit var mMatchesAdapter: MatchesAdapter

    private val viewModel: MatchesViewModel by viewModels {
        MatchesViewModelFactory(requireActivity().application, (requireActivity().application as MatchesApplication).repository)
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        setupRecyclerView()

        viewModel.matchesToday.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { matches ->
            mMatchesAdapter.differ.submitList(matches)
        }

        binding.srlMatchesToday.setOnRefreshListener {
            viewModel.getMatchesToday()
            binding.srlMatchesToday.isRefreshing = false
        }
    }
}
```

```
class MatchesAdapter(val fragment: Fragment): RecyclerView.Adapter<MatchesAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private val differCallback = object: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Matche>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Matche, newItem: Matche): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Matche, newItem: Matche): Boolean {
            return oldItem.status == newItem.status &&
                    oldItem.score.fullTime.home == newItem.score.fullTime.home &&
                    oldItem.score.fullTime.away == newItem.score.fullTime.away &&
                    oldItem == newItem
        }

        override fun getChangePayload(oldItem: Matche, newItem: Matche): Any? {
            val bundle: Bundle = bundleOf()
            if (oldItem.status != newItem.status) {
                bundle.apply {
                    putString(Constants.MATCH_STATUS, newItem.status)
                }
            }
            if (oldItem.score.fullTime.home != newItem.score.fullTime.home) {
                bundle.apply {
                    putInt(Constants.HOME_SCORE, newItem.score.fullTime.home)
                }
            }
            if (oldItem.score.fullTime.away != newItem.score.fullTime.away) {
                bundle.apply {
                    putInt(Constants.AWAY_SCORE, newItem.score.fullTime.away)
                }
            }
            if (bundle.size() == 0) {
                return null
            }
            return bundle
        }
    }

    val differ = AsyncListDiffer(this, differCallback)

    @SuppressLint("UseCompatLoadingForDrawables")
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val match = differ.currentList[position]
        holder.apply {
            Glide.with(fragment)
                .load(match.homeTeam.crest)
                .placeholder(fragment.resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_ball))
                .into(ivHomeTeamImage)
            Glide.with(fragment)
                .load(match.awayTeam.crest)
                .placeholder(fragment.resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_ball))
                .into(ivAwayTeamImage)
            tvHomeTeamName.text = match.homeTeam.name
            tvAwayTeamName.text = match.awayTeam.name

            when (match.status) {
                Constants.TIMED -> {
                    tvMatchTime.text = Constants.toTimeForTR(match.utcDate)
                    tvHomeTeamScore.text = "-"
                    tvAwayTeamScore.text = "-"
                }
                Constants.PAUSED -> {
                    tvMatchTime.text = Constants.FIRST_HALF
                    tvHomeTeamScore.text = match.score.fullTime.home.toString()
                    tvAwayTeamScore.text = match.score.fullTime.away.toString()
                }
                Constants.FINISHED -> {
                    tvMatchTime.text = Constants.FINISHED
                    tvHomeTeamScore.text = match.score.fullTime.home.toString()
                    tvAwayTeamScore.text = match.score.fullTime.away.toString()
                }
                else -> {
                    tvMatchTime.text = Constants.IN_PLAY
                    tvHomeTeamScore.text = match.score.fullTime.home.toString()
                    tvAwayTeamScore.text = match.score.fullTime.away.toString()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int, payloads: MutableList<Any>) {
        if (payloads.isNotEmpty()) {
            val item = payloads[0] as Bundle
            val status = item.getString(Constants.MATCH_STATUS)
            val homeScore = item.getInt(Constants.HOME_SCORE)
            val awayScore = item.getInt(Constants.AWAY_SCORE)
            holder.apply {
                tvMatchTime.text = status
                tvHomeTeamScore.text = homeScore.toString()
                tvAwayTeamScore.text = awayScore.toString()
                Log.e("fuck", status.toString())
            }
        }
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position, payloads)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return differ.currentList.size
    }

}
```

Comment: If you want this to update periodically, then someone, somewhere has to request a periodic callback.  I don't see that in this code.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LiveData only pushes new values if you command it to. Since you want to do it repeatedly, you need to create a loop. This is very easy to do using the `liveData` coroutine builder.

```
class MatchesViewModel(
    app: Application,
    private val repository: MatchesRepository
): AndroidViewModel(app) {

    val matchesToday = liveData {
        while (true) {
            if (Constants.checkConnection(this)) {
                val response = repository.getMatchesToday()
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    response.body()?.let {
                        emit(it.matches)
                    }
                }
            }
            delay(5000) // however many ms you want between fetches
        }
    }

}
```

If this is a Retrofit response, I think checking `isSuccessful` is redundant because `body()` will be non-null if and only if `isSuccessful` is true. So it could be simplified a bit from what you have:

```
class MatchesViewModel(
    app: Application,
    private val repository: MatchesRepository
): AndroidViewModel(app) {

    val matchesToday = liveData {
        while (true) {
            if (Constants.checkConnection(this)) {
                repository.getMatchesToday()?.body()?.matches?.let(::emit)
            }
            delay(5000) // however many ms you want between fetches
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it solves my problem and simplify my code. But i have a question tho. If an app with a thousands of user, use this and fetches in a second interval, does that have a downside? I mean the performance or server overload of requests. Does the big companies do it the same way? @Tenfour04

Comment: I don't know exactly what you're doing, to know whether it makes sense to proactively refresh like this. I'm not an expert on the subject, but push notifications may be more appropriate for this. I don't know anything about server-side programming.